# Seeking Mississippi Township Range Section shapefiles?

Tags: data, united-states, township-range-section

Does anyone know where I can get a full complete T/R/S for Amita County in MS?  Geocomm shp files looks incomplete.  The counties in Mississippi are not helpful.

I ended up finding the TRS from this website http://www.maris.state.ms.us/HTM/DownloadData/Statewide.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the entire State as a shapefile, for free. Attributes include township/range/section. This is PLS based on 24k maps. Maris has the Cadnsdi format of grid, which is newer.

[PLSS](http://www.gis.ms.gov/portal/detail.aspx?realm=All&aspect=Reference)

Comment: and also here http://www.maris.state.ms.us/HTM/DownloadData/Statewide.html

Comment: The link in the answer appears to be broken: `Server Error in '/' Application. Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference`

Answer (score 6):

The [national map](https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/Small-scale/data/Boundaries/plss00p020_nt00064.tar.gz) is one source.
[BLM Geocommunicator](http://www.geocommunicator.gov/GeoComm/lsis_home/home/) is another
There is a history of the plss system [here](https://nationalmap.gov/small_scale/a_plss.html)

[image: blm geocommunicator]
Depending on your location you will probably need the blm source data and the alt source data.

[image: alt source]

Comment: found it here http://www.maris.state.ms.us/HTM/DownloadData/Statewide.html

Comment: The first link appears to be broken.

Comment: I sent them a message. This page makes me think it should still be active. 
 https://www2.usgs.gov/science/cite-view.php?cite=2799

Answer (score 0):

As an update, PLSS provide national geodata here:
http://www.geocommunicator.gov/GeoComm/lsis_home/home/